# Copying winforms between projects in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

What is the best way to copy or cut/paste a form from one project to another project within a Solution in Visual Studio 2022? My Project is in "Windows Forms App" Net 6.0 windows template and copy the forms to "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" net 4.8.1 or lower, I tried it but I got some errors. Wish you give answers.

Comment: what did you copy?  I think it should work if you copied the Form.cs, Form.Designer.cs, and Form.resx files though I don't know how the .Net version would affect that.

Comment: I got this error


Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'PictureBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SJF Auto Parts Sales and Inventory System C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\Final Project\SJF Auto Parts Sales and Inventory System\SJF Auto Parts Sales and Inventory System\Form1.designer.cs 382 Active

Comment: @frankM_DN I tried to do it again it works, I only change on the namespace something. Thanks